# In Maven, can a profile override the modules (to not include any)

Tags: maven, maven-3

In `maven`, once you define your `modules` in you `pom.xml` all profiles aggregate the modules defined in them: (relevant part only)

```
<project>
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>
    <profiles>
         <profile>
             <id>pr1</id>
             <modules>
                 <moudule>module2</module>
             </modules>
```

If you perform a `mvn clean` it will pass the command to `module1`.

If you issue `mvn clean -Ppr1` it will pass along to `module1` and `module2`.

I wonder if in `maven 3` it is possible to have a `pom.xml` with submodules and override this. I mean to execute a profile that instead of add their own modules to the build force those like:

```
<project>
    <!-- omitted -->
    <modules>
        <!-- modules -->
    </modules>
    <build>
        <!-- build -->
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
             <!-- This profile with no modules -->
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The requirement might sound silly, but I just want to know if there is a mechanism like in plugin configuration.

```
<configuration self.combine="override"
```

Regards!

ssedano

Comment: Can you be more specific? I didn't understand your question at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not possible. Profile configuration is always merged with main configuration, so you only can add modules in your case.

What you can do instead, however, is to create a some kind of "default" profile (by `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` in `<activation>` section) that is enabled when no other profiles are invoked and put your default modules' list there. Then, when no profile is specified on Maven build call, this "default" profile is used, but when you call explicitly at least one profile, it's not, so you can this way define modules' list from scratch.

Comment: @Michael Sure, I can create a profile with the modules and deactivating. Can you point me to the site where you read this. I couldn't find it. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where you can find this trick described. But read Maven's [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) where `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` statement is used and covered and just implement it with your modules case. And to be strict: you don't deactivate this default profile. It's not active automatically when other profiles are used.

Comment: I meant the always merge thing. But this answer is fine enough

Comment: This is interesting because in my POM, the `<modules>` element isn't merged. I'm using Maven 3.0.5. Any idea why that might be?

Answer (score 15):

While the question is old, Google still ranks it highly, so it makes sense to add a new answer.

You can use the *activation by absence of a property* trick to achieve what you want.

```
<profiles>
        <!-- By default, include the modules -->
        <profile>
            <id>full-build</id>
            <activation>
                <!-- Activation by absence of a property. Run normally, without -Dskip-modules -->
                <property>
                    <name>!skip-modules</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>module1</module>
                <module>module2</module>
                <module>module3</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>

        <!-- No-modules build -->
        <profile>
            <id>no-modules</id>
            <activation>
                <!-- Activation by a property. Run with -Dskip-modules to activate -->
                <property>
                    <name>skip-modules</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <modules>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like this:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-xyz</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>www-ab</module>
        <module>www-cd</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <modules>
        <module>www-db</module>
        <module>www-it</module>
      </modules>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

If you are talking about such things. But i would recommend to be very carefull about such things.

It's only the question how you set activeByDefault. With this it's possible to create more or less any combination.

Comment: With this configuration all modules will run. This is not what I want. Thank you!