# Maven profiles - build without child projects

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I have a maven project with multiple child projects. I also have a maven dbunit plugin which I invoke from command line like this:

> mvn dbunit:operation -P test -pl .

`-P` is a profile switch where all necessary properties are stored (like db url, etc.)
I.e.:

```
<profile>
    <id>test</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</url>
        <username>ers</username>
        <password>ers</password>
        <useQualifiedTableNames>true</useQualifiedTableNames>
        <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.postgresql.PostgresqlDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
        <format>flat</format>
        <type>INSERT</type>
        <src>${basedir}/some_path/test.xml</src>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to specify `-pl .` parameter to build only one project (root/parent project) so that the dbunit data is loaded only once. Is it possible to specify some property directly in the profile, so only 1 project is being build? I tried `<pl>my_project</pl>` and `<project>...` - but no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `<modules>` element can be specified in a profile. So the solution would be to move the DBUnit setup code in a module and then:

```
<profile>
  <id>test</id>
  <modules>
    <module>db-unit-setup<module>
  </modules>
</profile>
```

If you activate this profile with `-P test`, only the single module `db-unit-setup` and the parent POM will be built. But since the parent POM is now an empty project (it's just a POM without any code), that shouldn't hurt.

Comment: Hi, as you suggested I'm trying to invoke a child project (named database) only. Using `<module>modules/common/database</module>`. I'm using existing project, as I would to avoid creating a new one. I wonder if `common` project (and all it's child will be build as well?) Anyway I'm getting an error: [ERROR] Two or more projects in the reactor have the same identifier, please make sure that <groupId>:<artifactId>:<version> is unique for each project: {com.foo.bar:database:2.1.0-SNAPSHOT=[../core/modules/common/database/pom.xml, ..core/modules/common/database/pom.xml]}

Comment: 1. It only builds the modules you specify; not the thing that might or might not be on the path to those modules. 2. The error happens because you add the same module twice to the list.

Comment: Okey, I can see that I have XML element `modules` specified already (before all profiles). And then I add it in profiles. Can I somehow override it?

Comment: That should be the default: If there is a `<modules>` element in the profile, the default one should be ignored completely. Which version of Maven?

Comment: I solved that by moving that existing `<modules>` to a different - default profile. :) Thanks for help!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682186/in-maven-can-a-profile-override-the-modules-to-not-include-any

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I still have the problem. DBunit plugin is being run for both: `database` project specified in the modules and `core` project which is that root/parent project. :C I guess I will have to stick with specifying the project explicitly in the command line.

Comment: [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] database ...................................... SUCCESS [5:07.578s]
[INFO] core pom ...................................... FAILURE [0.044s]

Comment: The error is related to the path of dataload file, as it is defined for relatively to the specific project. But not the error is problem, but the fact that the load is being run twice.

Comment: When the data is loaded twice, then you didn't clean the core pom properly.